# MonTeX (mls, manju, mongolian) with Latin script with diacritics

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, unicode, cjk

I am using the `montex` package to type text in Manchu (`manju`). In my documents, I also use Latin script with diacritics. When I load `montex`, these diacritics no longer appear, and when characters with diacritics reach 100, compilation fails altogether because of too many error. The `montex` documentation lists several encodings for Input and Output, the former including `utf-8` (pp. 19-22). As a non-programmer, I don't quite understand this, but it seems to me that none of the encodings listed in Table 4.1. "MonTeX Input Encodings" has one that can handle all the diacritics that I need. Does this mean that MonTeX is in fact incompatible with full `unicode`?

Working minimal example without `montex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén\\ %Latin texts with diacritics in Roman and Italics
\emph{yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén}
\end{document}
```

This looks good:

[image]

If I also load `MonTeX` and write some Manchu, it does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{mls} %Loading MonTeX
\begin{document}
\bithe{manju gisun}\\ %Typing Manchu
yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén\\
\emph{yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

In this file, the italicization has disappeared as well.

Looking through the list of encodings in the `MonTeX` manual, I find---perhaps I'm wrong?---that the best encoding is `english` as document language, and `mls` as encoding. But adding these options to

```
\usepackage[english,mls]{mls}
```

doesn't change the output.

The above is compiled with `XeLaTeX` but I've also compiled the same file with `LuaLateX` with the same result

Does anyone know what I should do to resolve this?

Comment: Looking at `mls.sty`, I see that the package `fontenc` an `inputenc` are required, which, afaik, clash with `fontspec`. Removing `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O` then compiling with `xelatex` or `lualatex` work in my machine. But I am not really that sure what is happening here. `:-)`

Comment: @hpesoj626 Hmm it doesn't solve it for me, the problem remains the same. Also, I do need some way to choose between fonts (in real documents, there will be CJK, italics, small caps and all sorts of stuff included...)

Comment: Can't you use `fontspec` for font selection (italics etc.)? And then you can use `CJK` or whatever for CJK fonts, I believe. The point is that `inputenc` isn't suitable if you are using XeLateX and `fontenc` probably isn't unless you know why you need it.

Comment: Load `mls` before `fontspec`. It is still wrong but the output is better and you get more meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 4):

Make a copy of `mls.sty`. Name it `mls-hacked.sty`. Apply the following patch.

```
--- mls-hacked.sty      2010-04-09 19:28:51.000000000 +0100
+++ mls-hacked.sty      2014-03-16 02:32:39.086050752 +0000
@@ -11,7 +11,7 @@
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % -------------------     identification     -------------------
 %
-\newcommand{\VersionDate}{2010/04/01}% 2002/07/01 with modified language name
+\newcommand{\VersionDate}{2014/03/16}% 2002/07/01 with modified language name
 \newcommand{\ImplementationLevel}{IVu}%
 \newcommand{\VersionKirill}{04}%
 \newcommand{\VersionMongol}{092}%
@@ -19,7 +19,8 @@
        \ImplementationLevel.\VersionKirill.\VersionMongol}%
 %
 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}%
-\ProvidesPackage{mls}[2010/04/01 IVu.04.092 Mongolian for LaTeX2e]%
+\ProvidesPackage{mls-hacked}[2014/03/16 IVu.04.092 Mongolian for LaTeX2e Hacked to remove inputenc]%
+\PackageWarning{mls-hacked}{This is NOT the official version of mls.sty. It will almost certainly break things badly. It will complain slightly less when used with XeLaTeX, however.}
 %
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % -------------------      initial code      -------------------
@@ -337,55 +338,6 @@
 }%
 %
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
-% -------- Loading of various codepage definitions -------------
-%
-% Input encodings supplied by MonTeX
-%
-\DeclareOption{mls}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cpmls}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{ncc}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cpncc}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{mos}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cpmos}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{mnk}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cpmnk}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{dbk}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cpdbk}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{ibmrus}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cpibmrus}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{koi}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cpkoi}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{ctt}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cpctt}{inputenc}}%
-%
-% Initial Unicode Mongolian utf-8 support. Experimental
-%
-\DeclareOption{utf8}{\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}}%
-%
-% Input encodings supplied by standard installations
-%
-\DeclareOption{1250}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp1250}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{1252}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp1252}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{437de}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp437de}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{437}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp437}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{850}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp850}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{852}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp852}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{865}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp865}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{cp1250}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp1250}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{cp1252}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp1252}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{cp437de}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp437de}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{cp437}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp437}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{cp850}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp850}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{cp852}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp852}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{cp865}{\PassOptionsToPackage{cp865}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{ansinew}{\PassOptionsToPackage{ansinew}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{applemac}{\PassOptionsToPackage{applemac}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{ascii}{\PassOptionsToPackage{ascii}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{atari}{\PassOptionsToPackage{atari}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{decmulti}{\PassOptionsToPackage{decmulti}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{isolatin}{\PassOptionsToPackage{isolatin}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{latin1}{\PassOptionsToPackage{latin1}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{latin2}{\PassOptionsToPackage{latin2}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{latin3}{\PassOptionsToPackage{latin3}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{latin5}{\PassOptionsToPackage{latin5}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{mac}{\PassOptionsToPackage{mac}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{next}{\PassOptionsToPackage{next}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{pc850}{\PassOptionsToPackage{pc850}{inputenc}}%
-\DeclareOption{roman8}{\PassOptionsToPackage{roman8}{inputenc}}%
-%
-%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % -------------------  execution of options  -------------------
 %
 \ProcessOptions
@@ -415,8 +367,6 @@
        \DeclareFontSubstitution{LMO}{bcghs}{m}{n}%
 \fi
 %
-\RequirePackage{inputenc}%
-%
 % PostScript detection; necessary for user-friendly
 % execution of vertical capsules
 %
```

will produce:

[image: Mongolian and emphasised text]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mls-hacked}% Note that the order is crucial - this must be loaded before fontspec
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\bithe{manju gisun}\\ %Typing Manchu
yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén\\
\emph{yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén}
\end{document}
```

Note that you can get the same output with `mls.sty` but it will complain a great deal about loading `inputenc` because this should not be loaded with XeLaTeX which assumes utf8 input.

Comment: does applying the patch means copying and pasting that contents into the end of the .sty file? or replacing the contents of the .sty with that contents?

Comment: @Mårten Which OS are you on? On Linux or OS X, you would just save that as a file, `patch`, in the same directory as `mls-hacked.sty` (i.e. the copy of `mls.sty`). Then you would just say `patch <patch`. I don't know how you apply patches on Windows, though.

Comment: If necessary, you *can* apply the changes by hand. The first two lines just give information about which file is to be modified. The lines which start with `-` are deleted. The lines which start with `+` are added. The lines which start with `@` specify locations in the file to help `patch` identify which lines to modify. The remaining lines provide context which also help `patch` to figure out which lines to modify. So you can basically find the lines in the file which I've deleted and the places were I've added lines. Pretty much all I've done is remove all lines related to `inputenc`...

Comment: @Mårten ..., modified the name of the file (to match the filename and to avoid classes with `mls`) and the file information, and added a warning to the effect that this is not the official style file and is expected to break stuff.

Comment: I get this:

Hunk #2 succeeded at 19 with fuzz 1.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 56.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 115.
Hunk #5 FAILED at 147.
Hunk #7 succeeded at 367 with fuzz 1.
Hunk #8 FAILED at 451.
Hunk #9 FAILED at 616.
5 out of 9 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file mls-hacked.sty.rej

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm on Mac OS.

Comment: @Mårten Hmm... Some of the hunks seem to be the products of my editor rather than substantive changes. Though I don't see why that would cause it to fail. I think you can ignore the failures, though. All of the hunks containing deliberate changes seem to have succeeded. The only ones which didn't look like changes to do with white spacing. What happens if you try compiling the MWE using `mls-hacked` as is?

Comment: @Mårten See edited patch. I think this should work but you will need to make a fresh copy of `mls-hacked.sty` by deleting the current one and copying the original `mls.sty` again to the new name.

Comment: Hmm I did that, applied the patch and compiled the mwe, but got the error message /mls-hacked.tex:5: LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly. And also mls-hacked/mls-hacked.sty:668: LaTeX Error: Command \G already defined.

Comment: @Mårten So the patch applied cleanly but you get errors compiling the MWE? I think I posted this on your other question but maybe not here. Take a look at my version above. In particular, make sure that you load `mls-hacked` **before** `fontspec`. Otherwise, you will get the error about `\G`.

Comment: I still get `LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly.` Is it because when I first apply the patch, I get: 

`patching file mls-hacked.sty`

`Hunk #2 succeeded at 19 with fuzz 1.`

`patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line`

`Hunk #4 succeeded at 367 with fuzz 1.`

Comment: @Mårten When you copy the patch, make sure that your editor does not cut off the spaces at the beginning of lines. For example, check that the fourth line starts ` %%%` and not `%%%`. Every line should start one of four characters: ` `, `-`, `+` or `@`. It would be easier if I could just post it as an attached file but SE doesn't offer a way to do that.

Comment: @Mårten Save http://bpaste.net/raw/190396/ as a plain text file. Make a fresh copy of `mls.sty` named `mls-hacked.sty` in the same directory. Then do `echo >> 190396` followed by `patch <190396`. (Or whatever you called the file when you saved it.) This avoids needing to worry about what your editor does to the beginning of lines. The `echo` is necessary because the paste service seems to delete the final newline which causes `patch` to fail.

Comment: Now the `patching file mls-hacked.sty` happens properly, but I still get the NFSS error. Sorry...

Comment: @Mårten And you are loading `mls-hacked` *first*?

Comment: Yes. This is the preamble:

`\documentclass{article}`
`\usepackage{mls-hacked}`
`\usepackage{fontspec}`
`\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}`
`\begin{document}`

Comment: @Mårten I'm running out of ideas since that works for me without error once I have the file patched properly. Is you installation of TeX up to date? Can you post the output you get somewhere? (Maybe to a pastebin and provide a link?) I don't get that error even with `mls.sty` - just complaints about the loading of `inputenc`.