# MonTeX and XeLaTeX fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, cjk, arabic

This is my second question regarding [MonTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/mongolian/montex), a follow up to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95804/montex-mls-manju-mongolian-with-latin-script-with-diacritics), which concerned a conflict between `xelatex` and `MonTeX` Since writing that question I contacted and received help from the author of the package, who managed to enable some of the commands offered by the `MonTeX` package by using this patch:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\font\bithehfont=bthhsm
\font\bithevfont=bthvsm
\newif\ifRtoL
\RtoLfalse
\newcommand{\bithe}[1]{%
    {\ifRtoL\bithevfont\else\bithehfont\fi#1}}%
\newcommand{\mabosoo}[1]{\bosoo{\bithehfont#1}}%
\newcommand{\bosoo}[1]{%
    \raisebox{1.25ex}{%
    \begin{turn}{270}%
        #1%
    \end{turn}}%
}%
```

I would need to enable some other commands offered by the package as well, notably the commands for horizontal and vertical Classical Mongolian and the smaller font sizes for both Manchu and Mongolian. The author of the package appears to be unavailable.

On this [forum](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=56800) someone states to have developed an alternative package for typesetting Mongolian, but the package is not available for download and the user appears to be inactive and cannot be contacted.

So my question is, could anyone help me to enable the following commands for use together with `xelatex` (in the "Simplified Transliteration Mode" for Mongolian):

`\bicig`

`\bithe`

`\mobosoo`

`\mabosoo`

(In both the `sffamily` [for Mongolian] and `rmfamily` [for Manchu] fonts)

Furthermore, the patch above will only enable writing Manchu in a fairly large font, too large to pair with 12pt text in Latin script. Is there a way to enable smaller type for the Manchu/Mongol commands as well?

That is certainly a lot of questions. If I haven't been clear, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a complete minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\usepackage{mls} %Not loading MonTeX since the patch below defines the command
\usepackage{rotating}
\font\bithehfont=bthhsm
\font\bithevfont=bthvsm
\newif\ifRtoL
\RtoLfalse
\newcommand{\bithe}[1]{%
    {\ifRtoL\bithevfont\else\bithehfont\fi#1}}%
\newcommand{\mabosoo}[1]{\bosoo{\bithehfont#1}}%
\newcommand{\bosoo}[1]{%
    \raisebox{1.25ex}{%
    \begin{turn}{270}%
        #1%
    \end{turn}}%
}%
\begin{document}
\bithe{manju gisun}\\ %Typing Manchu
yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén\\
\emph{yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The outcome with the command `\bithe` works as intended, except for the fact that the font size is too big. Since `\bicig` is not defined, the command `\bicig{bagadur}` naturally gives an error message.

Comment: Please post a **complete** Minimal (non-)Working Example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. This is especially important for this kind of case where I'm assuming a suitable example will have to include some Mongolian. Unless you are very lucky or very patient, you may prefer not to wait for somebody else to supply such on your behalf... That is, it may well be that somebody can help without knowing any Mongolian but it is less likely somebody will be able to help without trying to typeset some Mongolian. In any case, a complete example clarifies your question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I forgot. I've added it now.

Comment: Please see if my answer to your other question helps. Maybe it would also be helpful to know whether you actually need to use XeLaTeX. What cannot you do in pdfLaTeX that you need? I'm just thinking that problem might be easier to solve...

Comment: Thank you! I do need xelatex because I use it to typeset CJK, which is also in my real document

Answer (score 1):

Is this right?

[image: Possibly Mongolian...]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mls-hacked}% See answer to previous question - load order is important as is the patch
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\bithe{manju gisun}\\ %Typing Manchu
\bicig{bagadur}\\
yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén\\
\emph{yǐ mǎn zhōng wèn wén}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is right! It's just that they seem to be using the same font now, but if I understand it correctly I can use all the commands found in the original package now that a modified version of it is loaded, meaning I can modify it as I would with the regular package?

Comment: Hopefully... You'd just have to try it and see, I think. I would not honestly like to predict what might not work. This is partly because I'm not really in a position to test it since I have no idea (as you can tell from my question) what the output should be like!

Comment: You *may* need to do something with `fontspec` for font changes. I don't know how `mls` works or how you are proposing to change it! I would recommend just testing it out and seeing what does and doesn't work...